# PowerShell to update XML attribute where namespace

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-namespaces

I have successfully been able to access a XML file and update a particular attribute using PowerShell.

Here is the XML file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Provisioning xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2022/09/ProvisioningSchema">
  <Templates>
    <ProvisioningTemplate>
      <ClientSidePages>
        <ClientSidePage Title="Old Title" PageName="Dashboard.aspx">
        </ClientSidePage>
      </ClientSidePages>
    </ProvisioningTemplate>
  </Templates>
</Provisioning>
```

Here is the script:

```
$file = "C:\test.xml"
$xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.Load($file)
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//ClientSidePage[@PageName = 'Dashboard.aspx']")
$node.ContentTypeID = "New Title"
$xml.Save($file)
```

However, I am unable to update it when a namespace is in the mix, see below the addition of 'pnp:'

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pnp:Provisioning xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2022/09/ProvisioningSchema">
  <pnp:Templates>
    <pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
      <pnp:ClientSidePages>
        <pnp:ClientSidePage Title="Old Title" PageName="Dashboard.aspx">
        </pnp:ClientSidePage>
      </pnp:ClientSidePages>
    </pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
  </pnp:Templates>
</pnp:Provisioning>
```

This is the error I get:

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "'pnp' is an undeclared prefix. Line 2, position 2."
```

Can you please help me adjust the PowerShell as required? Or is simpler to just treat it as a string and replace 'Old Title' with 'New Title'.

Comment: The XML is not **well-formed** because root element doesn't have a namespace declaration. You need to fix the XML first.

Comment: It's the PnP PowerShell output for creating a Microsoft SharePoint site template so I'm trying to automate the update of an attribute once the site template has been exported to XML.

Comment: Ah, I've added the namespace declaration. It's a simplified version of the XML, with just the nodes, but yes sorry, I missed the namespace declaration.